# adding checkboxes value in react router dom urls

Tags: reactjs

I have the following checkboxes. I would like to know how to dynamically create urls links with the value of each of them.

Example :

```
 <Route exact path = {"/Pesquisar/:searchField/:page"} component = {withRouter(Pesquisa)}>
  </Route>
```

This is the url I have right now. If I mark CIRCULAR, i expect something like :

```
Pesquisar/some_content&circular=1/1
```

if I mark multiple checkboxes I would expect

```
  Pesquisar/some_content&circular=1&parecer=1&lei=1/1
```

[image]

How do I create this behavior using react router dom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `queryStrings` whenever you change the url by

```
npm install react-router
```

.

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router"
```

then

```
const history = useHstory();

history.push({
  pathname: '/dresses',
  search: '?checkbox=true'
})
```

Above code will add a query string to the url so we can use it and the url will be like

`https://myurl.com/dresses?checkbox=true`

then in your code

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
```

check if it exsists

```
params.has('checkbox')?params.get('checkbox'):""
```

or log it

```
console.log(params.has('checkbox')?params.get('checkbox'):"")
```

return will be `true`

I'm not sure but i think it will be string so if you want to use it check if it s equal to `"true"` like below

```
<Checkbox open = {params.has('checkbox')&&params.get('checkbox')==="true"?true:false} />
```